# how to use ajax with json.html

Tags: ajax

hi
i am doing on a project i need to use the json format for the data
but i am ask to put the json in the html 
after that use ajax and call into the javascript function
anyone know how can i put the json in html and how to use ajax
this is my json data

`["book":

```
    {
    "title":"JavaScript, the Definitive Guide",
    "publisher":"O'Reilly",
    "author":"David Flanagan",
    "cover":"/images/cover_defguide.jpg",
    "blurb":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit."
        },


    {
    "title":"DOM Scripting",
    "publisher":"Friends of Ed",
    "author":"Jeremy Keith",
    "cover":"/images/cover_domscripting.jpg",
    "blurb":"Praesent et diam a ligula facilisis venenatis."
        },

    {
    "title":"DHTML Utopia: Modern Web Design using JavaScript & DOM",
    "publisher":"Sitepoint",
    "author":"Stuart Langridge",
    "cover":"/images/cover_utopia.jpg",
    "blurb":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit."

}
```

]`

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, you're either misunderstanding it or you have a bad professor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so what it sounds like you want is just to be able to see What's returned by an AJAX call without doing any logic on the page itself.

Simply doing this:

json.html:

```
<html>
  <head><title>My JSON</title></head>
  <body>
    {
      "menu": {
        "id": "file",
        "value": "File",
        "popup": {
           "menuitem": [
               {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
               {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
               {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
        ]}
    }}
  </body>
</html>
```

And when you call your ajax function, the content of the page will be returned.

Comment: so after i put this in the html am i able to use this html url to use it in the ajax? eg.
xmlhttp.open("GET","HTMLPage4.htm",true);

Comment: Ah, I see what you're trying to do. Hang on let me edit this.

Comment: Is this more what you're looking for?

Comment: should be but i not sure that really cause i am ask to put the json data into the html and use the url to call in the ajax but how can combine the ajax function with the javascript function i have...cause in the javascript function i have to the coordinate i  want to retrieve through the ajax

Comment: how should i write in the ajax so that i won't retrieve the whole content but only the data eg. "File" from the value

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a subset of Javascript syntax.

You can write

```
var myArray = [ { prop: 123 }, ... ];
```

Comment: u mean in the html?cause i need to show the json data in the html so that i can use ajax xmlhttp with the url of the html(which contain json data using that format)

Comment: That's technically not JSON, its an array containing JSON. JSON is written using object syntax. See http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: @Cute: That doesn't make any sense.  HTML and JSON are two different formats.

Comment: ya but i put the data of into html and use the url to out in the ajax when i reqest for it